# Sum of the elements of a cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic subgroup of the group of units of a commutative unital ring $R$. What is the sum of the elements of $G$, i.e.
$$\sum_{x \in G}{x}?$$

[The answer is not difficult in the case that $R$ is an integral domain, i.e. it is $0$ whenever the exponent of $G$ does not divide $n$. Does a similar result hold?]

Answer (score 5):

If $G=\langle \zeta \rangle$ has order $n$, then the sum is $1+\zeta+\dotsc+\zeta^{n-1}$. It is killed by $\zeta-1$. Hence, if $\zeta-1$ is not a zero divisor, the sum is $0$. In general, the sum can be anything. Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n-1)$ and $\zeta=x$, the sum doesn't simplify. Actually this is the universal example for your question.

Comment: Actually, this is not a counterexample. Infact, one can show that if $n$ is odd localizations of the sum $S$ are well understood: $S_p = n$ if $x-1 \in p$, zero otherwise. Localizations of course determine $S$ globally

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $G$ to be any cyclic group, and consider the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$.